# Firebase Storage 'listAll' returns error 'Expected gs://bucketName/ to be a child element of gs://bucketName/fileName'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

When using `.listAll` to retrieve a list of items in the root folder of the storage bucket, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected
>   gs://MyBucketName/ to be a child element of
>   gs://MyBucketName/filename'

This only happens when listing the root folder, and not when listing a subfolder. The request is called as follows:

```swift
// Storage Reference
let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().root()

// List all items
storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Check what was found
    for item in result.items {
        print(item.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I know this project is old but I would like to know if you have solved this problem because I have the same one.

Comment: @MaxBrt18 I don't remember the details unfortunately, but I believe it was to do with the way I was working with / structuring the storage bucket, rather than the code itself? Sorry I can't be of more help